# Nonunital C*-Algebras: Morphism Contractive

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

**Problem**

Given C*-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Consider a *-morphism $\pi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$.

Then it is contractive: $\|\pi[\mathcal{A}]\|\leq\|A\|$

The proof I know critically uses:  $\pi[1]=1\in\mathcal{B}$.

But what if either $1\notin\mathcal{A}$ or $1\notin\mathcal{B}$ or $\pi[1]\neq1$?

Comment: Oops, sorry, had my mind elsewhere.

Comment: @sjvega: No problem. ;)

Comment: Either way, I'm somewhat sure that this works. Even more so, the usual proof of "contractiveness" of $*$-morphisms is done for (possibly)non-unital C*-algebras.

Comment: So where do you get stuck in completing the proof?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I'm just not sure wether I might have missed something as it seems so simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case: $1\in\mathcal{A}$**

Consider the C*-subalgebra $\overline{\mathrm{im}\pi}$ and the restricted morphism $\pi:\mathcal{A}\to\overline{\mathrm{im}\pi}$.

**Case: $1\notin\mathcal{A}$**

Adjoin a unit if necessary $\mathcal{B}\oplus\mathbb{C}$.

Adjoin a unit $\mathcal{A}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and extend the morphism by $\pi[A+a1]:=\pi[A]+a1$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out to you in the (at the moment) deleted answer: calculate the norm of $\pi'[A + a1]$. You don't need to assume that $A$ is a $C^\ast$ algebra you can show it for any Banach $\ast$-algebra $A$.

In other words, the following theorem holds:

Let $A$ be a Banach $\ast$-algebra and $B$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra and $\varphi: A \to B$ a $\ast$-homomorphism. Then $\varphi$ is norm decreasing.